# filter not working with primeng tree select

Tags: angular, filter, dropdown, primeng

I have implemented the new primeng treeselect component with selection mode as "checkbox".

```
<p-treeSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedNode1" [options]="nodes1" [metaKeySelection]="false"  selectionMode="checkbox" placeholder="Select Item" display="chip" [filter]="true"></p-treeSelect>
```

If I try to add a [filter]="true" as shown in the prime ng demo it throws error :

Can't bind to 'filter' since it isn't a known property of 'p-treeSelect'.

[start:client] 1. If 'p-treeSelect' is an Angular component and it has 'filter' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

[start:client] 2. If 'p-treeSelect' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

[start:client] 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

I have also added the required import-  import {TreeSelectModule} from 'primeng/treeselect';
Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update primeng. Filter for tree select is working for last version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).